# Is "printf-debugging" possible in Ltac?

Tags: coq, ltac

Is there a way to print the value of a variable (whether a hypothesis, tactic, term) in the middle of an Ltac procedure?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, use the `idtac` tactic.

You can pass `idtac` a constant string to print. It can also print identifiers (like hypothesis names) if you pattern match them, and it can print their types if you get access to them with pattern matching or `type of`. You can also print terms or the contents of Ltac let-bound variables. Finally, you can pass `idtac` multiple arguments to print them all out. You mentioned printing tactics - this is one thing that unfortunately you can't print with `idtac`. If you try to, you'll just get <tactic closure>.

Here are a bunch of examples:

`Goal True -> False.
  intro Htrue.
  idtac "hello world". (* prints hello world *)
  match goal with
  | [ H: True |- _ ] => idtac H (* prints Htrue *)
  end.
  match goal with
  | |- ?g => idtac g (* prints False *)
  end.
  let t := type of Htrue in idtac t. (* prints True *)
  let x := constr:(1 + 1) in idtac x. (* prints (1 + 1) *)
  idtac "hello" "there". (* prints hello there *)
  (* note that this is an Ltac-level function, not a Gallina function *)
  let x := (fun _ => fail) in idtac x. (* prints <tactic closure> *)
Abort.`

Comment: Note that you can also print out a thing in the middle of a tactic that returns a constr by writing `let __ := match goal with _ => idtac "foo" end in ...`